# How to do damage if touching a particle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to do a particle effect that damages anyone who touches it? I saw this in a one command youtube video and it seems possible, but I'm not sure if it requires armor stands. Can anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot detect or target particles. You would use an armor stand to mark a location to run commands, targeting the armor stand itself and not the particles.

Example, where an armor stand inflicts the Instant Damage effect to nearby players:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /effect @a[r=3] minecraft:instant_damage
```

And a `/particle` command to create particles at the armor stand's location as an indicator:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /particle witchMagic ~ ~ ~ 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 10
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can create particle zones with status effects

A relatively new entity, `area_effect_cloud`, is a region of particles that applies a status effect, modeled after the Ender Dragon's breath attack.

Try something like this, but replace every `x` with a number.

`/summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Particle:` <.put your particle here> `,ReapplicationDelay:5,Radius:xf,Duration:x,DurationOnUse:xf,Age:x,WaitTime:x,Effects:[{Id:20,Amplifier:1,Duration:20}]}`

Answer (score -1):

You could also add in some cool stuff by using the execute command

```
/execute @e[minecraft:area_effect_cloud] ~ ~ ~ /<put youre command here>
```